# switch, else if & or (Beginner Q)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a function which appears to always be returning true on the first condition irrelevant of input. I have been reading about using *switch* versus *else if* as I have 16 conditions to check and I want to ensure I have working 'best practice'

Can I achieve the same thing using both options:

```js
function lsaupdateTotals() {
  var x = variablename.value;
  var y = variablename2.value;


  if (x = 1) || (y = y > 1 && y < 280) {
      rdlsa = 7.45;
    } else if (x = 2 || (y = y > 281 && y < 460)) {
      rdlsa = 11.65;

      / or switch: /

      switch (x) {
        case 1:
        case y > 1:
        case y < 280:
          y = 7.45;
          break;
      }
```

Comment: You seem to be missusing `switch`, try to check up MDN reference in that regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few issues in your code:

- You're using `=` instead of `==` or `===` to check equality in your `if` statements. A single `=` sign *always* means "set equal to", not "is equal to?".
- In your `if` statement your parens make things a bit ambiguous. It's possible that this works just fine, but wrapping the entire question in parens is guaranteed to work as intended while also being completely clear.

Rewriting your `if` statement according to the above:

```js
  if (x == 1 || (y == y > 1 && y < 280)) {
    rdlsa = 7.45;
  }
  else if (x == 2 || (y == y > 281 && y < 460)) {
    rdlsa = 11.65;
  }
```

*(EDIT: Note that the `y == y > 1` part is almost definitely not doing what you want it to. That's asking "is y the same thing as y > 1?")*

In your `switch`, think of the value in each `case` as being a place holder for what you're putting into it. So in your example, using `y>1` doesn't make sense to evaluate against `x`, because it's asking if `x` is *equal to `y>1`, but `y>1` is always `true` or `false` and is independent of `x`.

Comment: This really clarifies this for me, I will test these corrections out. Thank you very much.

Comment: In your if conditions when you compare y then it should be (y > 1) only  (y== y>1) doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @MinalShah Agreed!

Answer (score 4):

There are several problem in your code:

1. In javascript, to compare 2 numbers (or strings) you have to use the syntax `===`, so `if (x = 1)` should became `if (x === '1')` (as I'm expecting `x` is a string).
2. The `if` condition should be in a parenthesis: `if (x = 1) || (y = y > 1 && y < 280) {` => `if ((x === 1) || (y === y > 1 && y < 280)) {`
3. It's not clear what you mean with `y = y > 1` (or `y === y > 1`) in first if (second parenthesis)
4. In switch/case syntax you cannot use `y>1`, please refer to switch/case syntax (internet is full of documentation)
5. When you put an assignment into the if (using `=` instead of `===`) the `if` statement consider `true` the condition if the value after the `=` is not `null`, `0`, empty string, `false` or `undefined`, for this reason when you write `if(x=1){` the condition is always `true`.

Comment: You can use something like `y>1` in a case, since it will be evaluated to `true` or `false` before being compared with `x`.

Comment: Yes but then you would need [`switch (true)`](https://medium.com/trabe/using-switch-true-in-javascript-986e8ad8ae4f) instead of `switch (x)`, and `case x === 1` instead of `case 1` in order to have a meaningful logic.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting the conditions wrong.
Please replace your code with the below lines

```
function lsaupdateTotals() {
var x = variablename.value;
var y = variablename2.value;


if ((x == 1) || (y > 1 && y < 280)) {
  rdlsa = 7.45;
  } else if ((x == 2) || (y > 281 && y < 460)) {
  rdlsa = 11.65;
 }

  / or switch: /

  switch (x) {
    case 1:
    case y > 1:
    case y < 280:
      y = 7.45;
      break;
  }
```

Comment: This solution still contains the error of having using single `=` instead of double- or triple-`=` for equality checks.